# Quitar lineal azul de un icono

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Hola resulta que puse estos iconos de redes sociales en el footer y realmente no recuerdo como se quitaba esa linea que creo que es ocasionada con el href que al pasar el puntero por el icono se genera detrás del icono una linea baja de color azul que casi ni se ve, cualquier ayuda se agradece.

```css
.logotipo-redes-sociales-footer {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <img class="logotipo-redes-sociales-footer" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/2d/47/bb2d47ee1407f37c1d1c25dbadd73ba3.jpg" alt="Facebook">
</a>
```

[image: Ahí se ve le hice zoom al máximo justo arriba de donde puse el mouse se origina esa lineal azul detrás de los iconos]

Comment: Ayudaría que des un mayor indicio del *problema* expuesto, ya que al momento el código no nos muestra de forma clara dicho comportamiento

Comment: ahi puse una imagen estimado

Comment: Creo que la línea no te sale en la ímagen, sino en tu fuente de iconos no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proba con lo siguiente:

```css
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda bro.